# I'm searching for sketch design software

Tags: website-design, software-recommendation, sketch-app, windows

I'm looking for software which can make sketches such as the one on the image below.

[image]

I need this software because i start new big project, with many pages. I'm working in a team and I need to present my ideas.

Software must be for Windows (not for MAC).

Comment: Photoshop, Illustrator, Indesign, Xara Designer, Corel Draw etc etc can all do this. Hell even paint can do this but its not the best option.

Comment: I look for software with drag and drop like Sketch.

Comment: [Webflow](https://webflow.com), perhaps? It's not exactly a mockup application nor cheap, but should do what you want. Or I guess it can be cheap, it just depends on how you use it.

Comment: well you can drag and drop elements in most apps. All you need is some templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with Artboards in Sketch and it sounds like you are already familiar with Sketch.

...but since you need to use it on a Windows machine, I would suggest Illustrator.